# Slider Range won't update Heat Map in HTML+JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, google-maps, heatmap

I am trying to update a Heat Map with some data from an array and I would like it to update the value/gradient of `PM25_centru` every time I move the slider, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this? The code is fully functional (no errors) but it just doesn't do what it needs to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    #map-container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 70%;
      order: 2;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
      background-color: white;
      height: 400px;
      width: 30%;
      padding: 20px;
      order: 1;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" min="0" max="12" step="1" value="0">
  <div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h2>Date</h2>
      <p id="selectedDataText"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, heatmap, data;

    var selectedDataText = document.getElementById('selectedDataText');

    function updateSelectedDataText(value) {
      selectedDataText.textContent = value.toString();
    }

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {
          lat: 47.8368,
          lng: 25.8756
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        map: map,
        radius: 200
      });
      loadData();

      document.getElementById('rangeInput').addEventListener('input', changeHeatmap);
    }
    var database = [{
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T13:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 418
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T14:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 416
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T15:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 417
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T16:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 416
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T17:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 418
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T18:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 419
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T19:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 415
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T20:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 416
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T21:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 415
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T22:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 410
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-18T23:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 413
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-19T00:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 414
      },
      {
        Data_si_ora_: '2023-05-19T01:00:00.000Z',
        PM25_centru: 418
      }
    ];

    function loadData() {
      data = database;
      updateHeatmap(0)
    }

    function changeHeatmap() {
      var rangeInput = document.getElementById('rangeInput');
      var selectedValue = parseInt(rangeInput.value);
      updateHeatmap(selectedValue);
    }

    function updateHeatmap(index) {
      var selectedData = data[index]['PM25_centru'];
      updateSelectedDataText(data[index]['Data_si_ora_']);
      var heatmapData = [];

      for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.8368, 25.8756);
        var weight = selectedData;

        heatmapData.push({
          location: latLng,
          weight: weight
        });
        heatmap.setData(heatmapData);
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working to me, just hard to see the difference between weights you are assigning.  If I make them different, the result changes.

Comment: Thank you @geocodezip, but do the results stay or it switches back to the initial gradient?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question, when I set the slider to 0 the display is different for setting it to other values,